# flutter map was called on a null value

Tags: flutter, dictionary, null

I try to get data from api. CallListDto class is empty according to user type. So, sometime this class is empty sometimes it has data. I populate dropdown menu items with this class.

My problem is, when this class is empty i got error. How can i solve this.

My model class is below

```
    Login loginFromJson(String str) => Login.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginToJson(Login data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Login {
  Login({
    required this.token,
    required this.callListDto,
  });

  String token;
  List<CallListDto> callListDto;

  factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Login(
        token: json["token"],
        callListDto: List<CallListDto>.from(
            json["callListDto"].map((x) => CallListDto.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "token": token,
        "callListDto": List<dynamic>.from(callListDto.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class CallListDto {
  CallListDto({
    required this.callId,
    required this.stationCode,
    required this.callType,
  });

  int callId;
  String stationCode;
  int callType;

  factory CallListDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CallListDto(
        callId: json["callID"],
        stationCode: json["stationCode"],
        callType: json["callType"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "callID": callId,
        "stationCode": stationCode,
        "callType": callType,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the model class check that str is not empty, for example

```
if (dataObject.isEmpty) return;
```